# Best practices when running Node.js with port 80 (Ubuntu / Linode)

Tags: linux, node.js, security, web-applications, configuration

I am setting up my first `Node.js` server on a `cloud Linux node` and I am fairly new to the details of `Linux admin`. (BTW I am not trying to use Apache at the same time.)

Everything is installed correctly, but I found that unless I use the `root login`, I am not able to listen on `port 80` with node. However I would rather not run it as root for security reason.

What is the best practice to:

1. Set good permissions / user for node so that it is secure / sandboxed?
2. Allow port 80 to be used within these constraints.
3. Start up node and run it automatically.
4. Handle log information sent to console.
5. Any other general maintenance and security concerns.

Should I be forwarding port 80 traffic to a different listening port?

Thanks

Answer (score 563, accepted):

## Port 80

What I do on my cloud instances is I redirect port 80 to port 3000 with this command:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

Then I launch my Node.js on port 3000. Requests to port 80 will get mapped to port 3000.

You should also edit your `/etc/rc.local` file and add that line minus the `sudo`.  That will add the redirect when the machine boots up. You don't need `sudo` in `/etc/rc.local` because the commands there are run as `root` when the system boots.

## Logs

Use the [forever](https://npmjs.org/package/forever) module to launch your Node.js with.  It will make sure that it restarts if it ever crashes and it will redirect console logs to a file.

## Launch on Boot

Add your Node.js start script to the file you edited for port redirection, `/etc/rc.local`.  That will run your Node.js launch script when the system starts.

## Digital Ocean & other VPS

This not only applies to Linode, but Digital Ocean, AWS EC2 and other VPS providers as well. However, on RedHat based systems `/etc/rc.local` is `/ect/rc.d/local`.

Comment: BTW, on Ubuntu, it is /etc/rc.local

Comment: Often the "-i eth0" flag will be an issue for virtual private servers.  Replace eth0 as needed.

Comment: If I add my Node.js start script to `/etc/rc.local`, won't it be executed as `root` on system boot? That would defeat the purpose of the port 80 redirect.

Comment: Yes, this is true.  If you start your node.js script from `/etc/rc.local` it will run as `root`.  However, security best practices are to never run a server as `root`.

Comment: But I run webserver on port 80, so the webserver wont work in this case. Please advise.

Comment: If you have a web server already running on port 80 then you'll need to configure it to be a reverse proxy for the Node.js backend server.

Comment: This works but not alongside my VPN (which I host on the same VPS).

Comment: What do you mean by `add Node.js script to /etc/rc.local` ? Do I simply need to add a line that calls the script, i.e. line : `node server.js` ?

Comment: Note that for the port redirect to work, the destination port needs to be opne on your firewall as well.

WRT starting a node instance on boot, we simply make use of the distributions's init scripts/systemd files that allow you to specify a user.

Comment: Let's say that I have two ip available, one which is bound to apache on port 80, how would I add the other one to the command above?

Comment: @JCM you would change `-i eth0` to `-i eth1`.  That would target the second interface instead of the first interface.

Comment: @Daniel what if the ip is inside a sub interface (eth0:cp1)?

Comment: @JCM I haven't actually used it with a sub interface, but I suspect it would work the same way.

Comment: @jamix & OP: Is there a solve for the rc.local command running as root?

Comment: @ndmweb Before we switched our Node.js app to Elastic Beanstalk where this is taken care of for us, we used `process.setgid()` and `process.setuid()` in the app itself to downgrade its permissions to those of a specially created `nodejs` system user.

Comment: @Daniel, The sockets sent to :80 does not seems to get forwarded to :3000 ? Can you help please ?

Comment: Make sure you get the `-i` correct, or remove it

Comment: what do you mean by add Node.js script to /etc/rc.local can you please tell me what should i wriye and also i i am using forever also ??

Comment: @Daniel when rerouting, does *ufw* also need to allow the specificed port?  Given your example, I've noticed this only works when 3000 is allowed via the firewall (`ufw allow 3000/tcp`), but that also allows anyone to access via that port; so an external person could get to the page by domainname.com (defaults to 80), domainname.com:80,  domainname.com:3000, and ip address (e.g, 123.456.789.012:80/3000).  I thought the desire was to allow TCP traffic on 80 to be served internally by port 3000; so all ports closed to external users except 80.

Comment: @bk138 I think I just repeated what you previously stated -- is that correct?  Is it possible to do port forwarding internally?

Comment: If I use this solution and later I want to remove this redirection of traffic, then how to do it?

Comment: fantastic, seccond line of the solution worked like a charm on one of my servers. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of adding the iptables changes to rc.local, how about editing `/etc/network/interfaces`, adding these two lines:
```pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
post-down iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules```

Comment: On a wireless laptop, can one leave out "-i eth0"? I tried this, but still doesn't work:

`iptables -F
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5000`

Comment: how do i undo this command?

Comment: very bad solution, you are loading your kernel with unnecessary traffic. all the packets are copied from one buffer to another, you are wasting resources. much better option is to setuid 0 to node process at the initialization so it can acquire privileged port, after bind() you just drop privileges.

Comment: If you are on AWS and using the ELB, just forward the ELB ports to the correct instance ports. This solution wouldn't work if you have multiple applications running on different ports.

Comment: Small point, on at least AWS: in the `/etc/rc.local` file there's the line `Please note that you must run 'chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local' to ensure that this script will be executed during boot.`

I had the line in, but hadn't run the `chmod` command and it didn't update when the machine was relaunched

Answer (score 124):

Give Safe User Permission To Use Port 80

Remember, we do NOT want to run your applications as the root user, but there is a hitch: your safe user does not have permission to use the default HTTP port (80). You goal is to be able to publish a website that visitors can use by navigating to an easy to use URL like `http://ip:port/`

Unfortunately, unless you sign on as root, you’ll normally have to use a URL like `http://ip:port` - where port number > 1024.

A lot of people get stuck here, but the solution is easy. There a few options but this is the one I like. Type the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libcap2-bin
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep `readlink -f \`which node\``
```

Now, when you tell a Node application that you want it to run on port 80, it will not complain.

Check this [reference link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pm2-to-setup-a-node-js-production-environment-on-an-ubuntu-vps#give-safe-user-permission-to-use-port-80)

Comment: This is the better, simpler answer.

Comment: Also, added detailed answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281895/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-http-80-port-permission-denied/23281904#23281904

Comment: How does a web server like NGINX run on port 80? Does it do something similar?

Comment: @EricAndrewLewis: I will say it depends. This error will show up when you are running the server in non-root mode. What if you are running the Nginx server as root user!
 Also, if running as normal user and getting error. Run above commands to give safe permissions to access the port. Also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369480/vagrant-and-nginx-only-works-on-ports-other-than-80

Answer (score 17):

**Drop root privileges after you bind to port 80 (or 443).**

This allows port 80/443 to remain protected, while still preventing you from serving requests as root:

```
function drop_root() {
    process.setgid('nobody');
    process.setuid('nobody');
}
```

A full working example using the above function:

```
var process = require('process');
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.write("Success!");
    res.end();
});

server.listen(80, null, null, function() {
    console.log('User ID:',process.getuid()+', Group ID:',process.getgid());
    drop_root();
    console.log('User ID:',process.getuid()+', Group ID:',process.getgid());
});
```

See more details at this [full reference](https://thomashunter.name/blog/drop-root-privileges-in-node-js/).

Answer (score 9):

For port 80 (which was the original question), Daniel is exactly right.  I recently moved to `https` and had to switch from `iptables` to a light nginx proxy managing the SSL certs. I found a useful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17027443/2669596) along with a [gist](https://gist.github.com/gabrielhpugliese/5759232) by [gabrielhpugliese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1164249/gabrielhpugliese) on how to handle that. Basically I

- [Created an SSL Certificate Signing Request (CSR)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/InstallCert.html) via [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/)

  ```
  openssl genrsa 2048 > private-key.pem
  openssl req -new -key private-key.pem -out csr.pem
  ```
- Got the actual cert from [one of these places](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Security/Public_Key_Infrastructure/PKIX/Tools_and_Services/Third_Party_Certificate_Authorities/) (I happened to use [Comodo](http://www.comodo.com))
- [Installed nginx](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html)
- [Changed the `location` in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/example_ssl.conf` to](https://gist.github.com/gabrielhpugliese/5759232)

  ```
  location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
  ```
- [Formatted the cert for nginx by `cat`-ing the individual certs together](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1365&nav=0,1,95) and linked to it in my nginx `example_ssl.conf` file (and uncommented stuff, got rid of 'example' in the name,...)

  ```
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert_bundle.cert;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private-key.pem;
  ```

Hopefully that can save someone else some headaches. I'm sure there's a pure-node way of doing this, but nginx was quick and it worked.