# Meteor SSL connection

Tags: ssl, meteor

I'm trying to connect to my Meteor project via SSL/TLS.

Therefore I did the following:

**meteor add force-ssl**

in the meteor folder.
Then I start the programm with 'meteor'.

Everything is running fine on localhost, but if I want to connect to the server with giving the IP and Port over http, I get redirected to a https connection with the same IP and an 'Unable to connect message'.

Note: I created a certificate on my own an put it into the Meteor/server folder.

Does anyone know my mistake?

Answer (score 12):

If you need to enable [SSL support](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up#ssl-support) for your Meteor app deployed with [Meteor Up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up). Now it has the support for SSL. You just need to tell where the SSL certificate and the key are.

If you are not familiar with the process of generating a SSL certificate, follow [this guide](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up#ssl-support).

> Disclaimer: I'm the author of Meteor Up.

Answer (score 11):

You can't just put the certificate inside Meteor/server folder. You will need a web server to proxy the request and configure that server with your certificate (Docs also say that, search for force-ssl: http://docs.meteor.com/)

I recommend you to put an nginx instance as the proxy. Here an example of how to do it: http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-nginx.htm

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have absolutly no idea what to do.

I have a Meteor Server running on localhost Port 3000. I have installed nginx. But now I don't know how to proceed. What is my nginx virtual host file? Is it /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf ??

Comment: Well, if you know how to do it with Apache, then do with it. But I've made a gist for you. It's just a start of configuration that should run: https://gist.github.com/gabrielhpugliese/5759232. You can put it on `nginx.conf` inside the `http {}` scope (note that I've written it on the gist too). If this runs ok, don't forget to accept the answer :)