# Cannot connect to meteor server running on virtualbox when using force-ssl

Tags: ssl, meteor

I have a windows 8.1 machine running ubuntu 14.x on a virtualbox. I'm running meteor inside that virtualbox. I've bridged the connection and turned off the firewall on both machines. I'm able to connect to the internet from the virtual box, and I can telnet from the windows host into the ubuntu machine.

I can also connect to meteor apps that are not using the force-ssl package; however, I CANNOT connect to meteor apps that are using force-ssl!

If I run "meteor remove force-ssl" I can connect to the app. Any thoughts? Thanks.

EDIT - by connect to the app, I mean "`http://[ip_address_of_guest]:3000/`" in a browser on the host machine. I've tried both http and https.

Comment: I've run into this same problem multiple times since posting. Other instances include: meteor run android-device -p 3000 (i.e. trying to run a phonegap app on a physical android device) and trying to connect to a meteor server with my phone (e.g. 192.168.x.x:3000). Both of the former work if I remove the force-ssl package.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Meteor but, from [this documentation](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/force-ssl), it looks to me like you are seeing the **intended** behaviour ...

> "This package, part of Webapp, causes Meteor to redirect insecure
>   connections (HTTP) to a secure URL (HTTPS). Use this package to ensure
>   that communication to the server is always encrypted to protect users
>   from active spoofing attacks.
>
> To simplify development, unencrypted connections from localhost are
>   always accepted over HTTP.
>
> Application bundles (meteor bundle) do not include an HTTPS server or
>   certificate. A proxy server that terminates SSL in front of a Meteor
>   bundle must set the standard x-forwarded-proto header for the
>   force-ssl package to work.
>
> Applications deployed to meteor.com subdomains with meteor deploy are
>   automatically served via HTTPS using Meteor's certificate."

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17027443/1544075) clarifies.

I am about to try the Digital Ocean guide, ["How To Deploy a Meteor.js Application on Ubuntu 14.04 with Nginx"](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-js-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx), myself to see if it correctly documents the required set up steps.  I'll update with my results.