# How to redirect port 80 port 900 Node Server using apache2

Tags: node.js, apache, ubuntu, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-14.04

I have a node app running on port 9000 with forever on Ubuntu 14.04. I can simply run my app on port 80. But it needs root privileges. And I found that It's not a good idea run a server software on port 80 with root privileges. So the alternative is reverse proxy. To be honest I know nothing about reverse proxy or the way to do it. So can anyone guide to through it ?
simply what i want to do is run my node app on port 9000 and make sure it's available on port 80 using apache2.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

Comment: check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573668/best-practices-when-running-node-js-with-port-80-ubuntu-linode