# Jquery web page and node.js as server

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am completely new to node.js

I am web developer and I already have a jquery mobile webpage. My team is moving the server from php (same server as my page) to node.js and I have a problem due to cross domain.

How should I tell them to configure node server to work in the same port as apache? Now apache is running on 80 and node.js in 8080 but we want to change the second one to be able to work with my page.

If this is not possible, would be possible to return my webpage from node.js server? How should we do this? Webpage just depends on the server to get data.

Comment: It is not possible for two processes to listen on the same port. If Apache is listening on port 80, no other process can do the same.

You *can* configure Apache to *proxy* specific calls to Node.js listening on port 8080.

Comment: Do you know a tutorial for configuring that?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect port 80 to port 8008 using this command:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Hope that helps.

Got this from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573668/best-practices-when-running-node-js-with-port-80-ubuntu-linode).

Comment: How does this allow both Apache and Node.js to listen on port 80?

Comment: Not both obviously! You can only run one server per port!

Comment: So this is not an answer to the question.