# Node.js app not loading on Ubuntu 12.04 - this site cant be reached

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm developing a node.js (SEAN.JS) app. On my local machine the app works normal at localhost:3000, After I run grunt, But on my server (Ubuntu 12.04 - angular.pling.cc:3000) it doesnt.

The error I'm recieving is:

`"This site can’t be reached. angular.pling.cc took too long to respond."`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

solved. i redirected port 80 to 3000 with this command:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

as suggested here: [Best practices when running Node.js with port 80 (Ubuntu / Linode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573668/best-practices-when-running-node-js-with-port-80-ubuntu-linode)