# How do I safely run a Node.js server on port 80 with Amazon Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

The following error is common for people trying to run a Node.js server on port 80.

```
Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80
```

I used to solve this on my Amazon EC2 server simply by using

```
sudo node app.js
```

Now I've learned not to use that method for security concerns. A good solution as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573668/best-practices-when-running-node-js-with-port-80-ubuntu-linode) is to use:

```
sudo apt-get install libcap2-bin
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep `readlink -f \`which node\``
```

However I'm not sure how to implement either solution on an AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance, where I don't seem to have SSH access the way I did for the AWS EC2 server, and the only way I seem to have for running anything is in my `package.json` file like this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node init"
  }
}
```

So I have no idea how I would run other types of commands. How is this done?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Beanstalk has a proxy build into it listening on port 80.  Your Node.js app should only listen on `process.env.PORT`.  Once it's done that, you'll be good to go.

Comment: and who sets `process.env.PORT`?

Comment: I am not sure if it has been changed but in my case even I set the port number to process.env.PORT it returns 8081 for https rather than 443

Comment: @CodyBugstein The Beanstalk system sets that.

Comment: @ZhangZhan Yeah, you shouldn't expect :443... Beanstalk uses its own proxy and what not internally.

Comment: @Brad But the problem is if I use process.env.PORT it redirect the browser to port 8081 which is not ideal as it will be displayed in the browser address and also not firewall friendly.

Comment: @ZhangZhan No, it won't.  That will only happen if your code does this redirect... which you shouldn't do.  This is how Beanstalk works.  There is a proxy set up internally. Externally, port :443 is used, and your users don't need to know or care that Beanstalk does something else internally.

Comment: @Brad you are correct. I did the redirection in my code and that is why it is going to 8081. Thank you.

Comment: Here's the link for the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-proxy.html

Answer (score 1):

Elastic beanstalk will route requests to your instances (at port 80 by default) from its load balancer. So in case you want to expose a particular port, you can add an entry to the load balancer listeners with the load balancer port as your desired port and instance port as 80.
Hope this helps. Can elaborate further if needed.

Answer (score 1):

For the

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node init"
  }
```

You may use below to specify your running code is `app.js`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  }
```

In the `app.js`, if you use express.js

```
const port = process.env.port || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Sever console log.")
});
```

Then you have a add a parameter in Elastic Beanstalk > Select your Environment > Configuration > Edit the software configuration > add a Paramerter > Name: port Value: 8080