# running nodejs application on virtual hosting that listens at different port

Tags: node.js, virtualhost

I am running my nodejs server with port 8443 on localhost.

i.e. `http://localhost:8443` or `https://localhost:8443`

Now, I have deployed the project on one server instance with  IP say `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

I have started the node server on it for the same port.

From this server instance, I can access the node server locally as I can do for my localhost machine.

But How can I access the node server publicly from outside of server at 8443?

i.e. `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8443`

Comment: listen(8443, '0.0.0.0'); or without 0.0.0.0: listen(8443);

Comment: And make sure that your firewall accepts inbound TCP connections on port 8443

Comment: [Redirect port 80](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573668/best-practices-when-running-node-js-with-port-80-ubuntu-linode)

Comment: @magreenberg  RIYAJ does not want to redirect 80th to 8080 and 443 to 8443. He is trying to access app globally at defined port.
also it's better to set app behind normal webserver (for example: nginx, apache), cuz every app has it's static files, that's not recommended to handle on nodejs app.

Answer (score 0):

checkout this simple example:

```
var
  fs = require('fs'),
  express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  http = require('http'),
  https = require('https');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(8080, '0.0.0.0', function () {
  console.log('App listening at http://0.0.0.0:8080');
});

var httpsConfig = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('path/to/certificate.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('path/to/certificate.crt')
};
var httpsServer = https.createServer(httpsConfig, app);
httpsServer.listen(8443, '0.0.0.0', function () {
  console.log('App listening at https://0.0.0.0:8443');
});
```

Comment: So,is it virtual hoasting for nodejs?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN It's an example code to run expressjs app on 8443 port that listens on all network interfaces (devices) of server. If it's cheap php hosting service so of course it will not run (: more info about hosting will be usefull