# How do I show a webpage tied to a port?

Tags: port

I don't have a very good understand on ports so I'm not sure how to explain this.

I have an app on my site running on, for example, `www.url.com:1234`

I need the url to be like `www.url.com/class/subfoler/index.html`

How do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: This is a question for serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the port with the domain.

Try:

```
http://www.url.com:1234/class/subfoler/index.html
```

Comment: That's what I'm using now, so actually I'm trying to not include the port in the url so I can use relative links. But I've learned that it is impossible to do so, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Oh I completely missed your question!
Here's how you do it on linux: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573668/best-practices-when-running-node-js-with-port-80-ubuntu-linode what os are you running?

Answer (score -2):

You can try using an iframe tag in your index.html file which would serve your app's (port 1234) URL from inside your main (port 80) website, like so:

<iframe src="http://www.url.com:1234">If you can read this, your browser does not support iframes.</iframe>

Comment: The user did not ask anything about iFrames.

Comment: The user did not specify how this needs to be done, so perhaps an iframe will help in this occasion. Your answer above assumes that the app and the website are one and the same (which is probably incorrect).

Comment: The user asked how to access www.url.com/class/subfoler/index.html on port 1234, how does you answer have anything to do with the question?

Comment: No, actually the user asked how to make the URL accessible from a webpage on port 80, even though it is actually running on port 1234.

Comment: Thanks, I know about this workaround, but I was trying to use relative links (although now I learned that it is impossible)