# Redirect web server from port 5000 to port 80 on localhost (Fedora)

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, firewall, iptables

On Fedora 24, a web server (Node.js) is running (standalone, no apache/others) on port 5000. Trying to making it accessible on port 80.

http://localhost:5000 works

Tried this:

```
systemctl stop firewalld
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -F
iptables -X

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 5000
```

http://localhost doesn't work

Tried this

```
systemctl restart firewalld
firewall-cmd --add-service=http --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=external --add-masquerade 
firewall-cmd --zone=external --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=5000 
firewall-cmd --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=5000 
firewall-cmd --list-all
FedoraWorkstation (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: wlp3s0
  sources: 
  services: mdns ssh dhcpv6-client samba-client https http
  ports: 1025-65535/tcp 1025-65535/udp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports: port=80:proto=tcp:toport=5000:toaddr=
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

**Additional info**
Tried these

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat --list

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http redir ports 5000
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https redir ports 5000

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

ifconfig 
enp0s25: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500

ip route 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0  proto static  metric 600 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp3s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.4  metric 600
```

For others it just works:
[Best practices when running Node.js with port 80 (Ubuntu / Linode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573668/best-practices-when-running-node-js-with-port-80-ubuntu-linode/)

Running node as root on port 80 works. Note, there's no IPv4:

```
netstat -tpln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/systemd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4433            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3977/deluge-gtk     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:51157           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3977/deluge-gtk     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      900/postgres        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17500           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3203/dropbox        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17600         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3203/dropbox        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17603         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3203/dropbox        
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd           
tcp6       0      0 :::4433                 :::*                    LISTEN      3977/deluge-gtk     
tcp6       0      0 :::51157                :::*                    LISTEN      3977/deluge-gtk     
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      900/postgres        
tcp6       0      0 :::17500                :::*                    LISTEN      3203/dropbox        
tcp6       0      0 :::34017                :::*                    LISTEN      10532/code          
tcp6       0      0 :::5858                 :::*                    LISTEN      30394/node          
tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN      30394/node
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
firewall-cmd --add-service=http --permanent
firewall-cmd --add-service=https --permanent
firewall-cmd --add-masquerade --permanent
firewall-cmd --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=5000 --permanent

#make port forwarding work on localhost
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT --source 127.0.0.1 --destination 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using `iptables` for things like this, but on Fedora you'd need to setup the firewall appropriately. Also this question has nothing to do with Node.js

```
firewall-cmd --add-service=http --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39216/cannot-connect-to-fedora-on-port-80

Comment: Thanks, edited to remove nodejs.

# firewall-cmd --add-service=http --permanent
FirewallD is not running

I tried starting it, running these, then iptables again, still doesn't work. Then stopped firewall again.

Comment: Also tried:
firewall-cmd --add-service=http --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=external --add-masquerade
firewall-cmd --zone=external --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=5000
firewall-cmd --reload

Comment: What was the solution then?

Comment: see the other answer