# How can I run my nodejs with nodemon on port 80

Tags: node.js

I have my nodejs running on port 9090 and I somehow made it work on port 80 by using the following setup

sudo apt-get install libcap2-bin
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep

and when I run as nodejs server.js 80, I'm able to run my client as localhost without any port specified.

But when I run the same with nodemon server.js 80, it throws an error

Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80

How can I run it with nodemon and port 80

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need elevated privileges to bind to a port below 1024. try `sudo nodemon server.js 80`.

Comment: Is this the same unix machine with nodemon installed?

Comment: What happens when you run sudo nodejs server.js?

Comment: It works fine, but will not restart on any uncaught error.

Comment: Thats odd. Command not found? Are you sure nodemon is installed and you didnt make a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You need root permissions to run on 'privileged' ports, so run it as `sudo`. I advise you to use a proxy like nginx for proxying your requests to ports such as 80, or atleast re-routing your traffic via iptables (how-to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573668/best-practices-when-running-node-js-with-port-80-ubuntu-linode)).