# Node.js not accepting connections on port 80

Tags: node.js, nmap

I am running my node server on ubuntu with `sudo node index.js`
Running `curl http://localhost/health-check` gives a response but if I use the public IP, it does not get any response

Running `sudo netstat -ntlp`

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
59739/node
```

Running `nmap -A -T4 myDomainName`

```
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-11-22 12:32 UTC
Nmap scan report for myDomainName (IP address)
Host is up (0.0011s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT    STATE  SERVICE VERSION
...
80/tcp  closed http
443/tcp closed https
```

Running  `nmap localhost`

```
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-11-22 12:28 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000062s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
```

Lastly  `sudo ufw status`

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Port 80 is open on localhost but not open on the domain name/ public ip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practices when running Node.js with port 80 (Ubuntu / Linode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573668/best-practices-when-running-node-js-with-port-80-ubuntu-linode)

Comment: _I am running my node server on ubuntu with sudo_. Please, don't.

Comment: why, what is the problem with running with sudo?