# How to run a nodejs server on port xxxx and access it through another port?

Tags: routes, iptables

I´m using centOS and I want to redirect port xxxx to anthor port.

node.js is installed.
I have tried it with this note:
[Best practices when running Node.js with port 80 (Ubuntu / Linode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573668/best-practices-when-running-node-js-with-port-80-ubuntu-linode)

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

I get an error-message:
can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)

If there is another way to redirecting ports just let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use Nginx as a reverse-proxy. Check out DigitalOcean's [excellent tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-centos-7) for setting up Node.js in production, which shows how to use Nginx in the way you're trying to achieve. I.e.:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```