# Create local host without any number

Tags: python, node.js

When I create a local host from Nodejs or Python it starts
local host:8000 or 3000
i don't want 8000 or any number.
How can I get only local host?

Comment: That's the port number & it's mandatory. If you mean you don't want that number to show up on the browser URL bar, then you'll have to run your server on port 80 or 443

Comment: [node.js url without port number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49430550/3890632)

Comment: This is not PHP. It is required that you use a port.

Answer (score 2):

This number is called PORT number. Every URL, for example `localhost` also have PORT `80` by default but you don't need to type it as of `HTTP` request connects to PORT `80` as default behavior and `HTTPS` connects to port 443.

To archive this, you can follow/choose one of following two ways.

1. RUN `NODEJS`/`PYTHON` app on PORT 80 or PORT 443 (if you have SSL certificates). This way you you can access it by`localhost` without adding PORT number to URL.
2. Install web-server like `apache` or `nginx` and use `reserve proxy` feature to archive it.

**NOTE**

- Point 1: This is easy way and does not need knowledge required for point 2.
- Point 2: You must have knowledge of web-servers and `reserve proxy` feature.

Comment: Is port 143 the 443? (143 is for IMAP)

Comment: Yup @jtwalters that's typo. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

**Port Number Description:** the number you see is the port number. it distinguishes between different applications in a single host (your computer for your case). for example let's say you have a website and a file server running on your computer. when you type `localhost` in your browser, it reaches your computer ip address but how does it know which application to request for data? webserver or file server? this is where the port number comes handy. when webserver is running on port 9000 for example and you type `localhost:9000`, you are telling your browser to go to your computer (localhost) and ask webserver application (port 9000) for data.

**Answer to Your Question:** if you type `localhost` without any port number, it connects to port 80 of the host by default (it's a convention or so) so if you run your application on port 80, you get what you wanted.

**Extra:** there is also a 443 port which is the default port for https request but i don't think you are using ssl right now.