# Run node js on ports 80 without running as root

Tags: node.js, port, port80

i want to run my node.js application on port 80 without running it as root

```
$> which node
/usr/bin/node
```

I have tried to use setcap but it's not working:

```
$> sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /usr/bin/node
Failed to set capabilities on file `/usr/bin/node' (Operation not 
permitted)
The value of the capability argument is not permitted for a file. Or 
the file is not a regular (non-symlink) file
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practices when running Node.js with port 80 (Ubuntu / Linode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573668/best-practices-when-running-node-js-with-port-80-ubuntu-linode)

Answer (score 4):

Ports below 1000 require sudo privilege. You can use the following command to allow it to bind to port 80 without sudo:

```
sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' `which node`
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have used port redirection, not with iptables but with ufw

https://serverfault.com/questions/238563/can-i-use-ufw-to-setup-a-port-forward