# Proxy a node/react application in an apache server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, apache, reverse-proxy

Using forever to forever run the node server on the virtual machine, I am unable to get the app to run without explicitly adding the port in the url like so: URL.com:8080
If I don't use the port in the URL, I do load up the file structure of the application.

Steps to reproduce: I have a create-react-app application.On the virtual server I run 'npm run build' to make sure I have a build to serve. I then run forever start on the root of the application.

The code below should give all the necessary details. I can provide more if you need.

I have spent so much time tweaking the .conf file to try different configurations but I can't seem to get it. I am using it and successfully hosting two static html sites but not this node application.

Package.json:

```
...
"main":"server/index.js",
"proxy":"http://localhost:8080"
...
```

Apache url.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName URL.com
    ServerAlias URL.com:8080/
    DocumentRoot /var/www/nameOfApp/
<Directory />
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/nameOfApp/public>
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Node server file using express:

```
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/../build`));
```

I've also made sure I have the modules enabled to allow for proxying. So I think essentially, what I need is to request this site and not need the :8080 at the end.

Comment: You enabled the proxy module for Apache, but do you set it up correctly? Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831594/apache-and-node-js-on-the-same-server

Comment: I only used a2en... to enable them. Is that not the right way? Is there additional configs that I need to modify? @jimmy5312

Comment: I ran through the link you sent me and added the ProxyPass line on my proxy.conf file and made sure the two LoadModules were enabled. Then I added a 'node' folder in /var/www and changed the DocumentRoot in the site.conf to point to that and I still get the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration that eventually worked was as simple as this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourdomain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Looks like I was over complicating it trying to create a complicated proxy but the solution was very simply adding this to the config for the node application and then running sudo systemctl restart apache2 and everything worked beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

Apache and NodeJS are 2 different and separate application.
You interact with them by sending request to the port that they are listening to. In your case here,

> Apache is listening at port 80
>
> Your NodeJS application is listening at port 8080

So all request to port 80 will be handled by Apache, and since you do not has an index.html, Apache will default to just list out the files and directory (Options Indexes). Up until this point, your node application do not know anything about your request.

So what you need to do is define some endpoint, say url.com/node, and tell Apache to forward all request of this endpoint to port 8080 and let your node application to do the job.

How to do this?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

[Best practices when running Node.js with port 80 (Ubuntu / Linode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573668/best-practices-when-running-node-js-with-port-80-ubuntu-linode)

[Node.js + Nginx - What now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009324/node-js-nginx-what-now)

Hope this points you to the right direction.

Comment: I'll try that out. Thank you!

Comment: I was able to get the front end rendering. But every call to the server came back 404. So If I manually added the port :8080 it would correctly catch the request but only then