# I am running a react app locally on apache2 server. It gives error URL not found on this server

Tags: reactjs, apache2

[image]

This is a simple react memory game app which i'm trying to run on apache. The app runs fine but when i copy the invite link produced and paste it in a newtab it gives error saying "'the requested url was not found on this server". It runs fine when i run it using "npm start" from the terminal but not on apache. This is my first day with apache so bear with me if the question is silly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured a reverse proxy in your Apache server? Because this is required for Apache to know how to handle URLs dynamically generated by React.

Example (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56409945/2203828)):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourdomain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

If you don't want to meddle with your Apache setup your only option is to use a [HashRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter) component, so all URLs will be preceeded by a `#`, this way your application's entrypoint is always its base URL and the routing in decided by React from the hash paremeter.

Examples:

```
<HashRouter
  basename={optionalString}
  getUserConfirmation={optionalFunc}
  hashType={optionalString}
>
  <App />
</HashRouter>
```

```
<HashRouter basename="/calendar"/>
<Link to="/today"/> // renders <a href="#/calendar/today">
```