# "sudo npm start" doesn't work but "npm start" work

Tags: node.js, npm

so I'm trying to run my react dev server on port 80, I need to use sudo to use PORT=80

but when I try to start the server with

```
sudo npm start
```

it returns error like this:

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! counter-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the counter-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
the log file
```

the log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.12.1
3 info using node@v8.10.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle counter-app@0.1.0~prestart: counter-app@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle counter-app@0.1.0~start: counter-app@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle counter-app@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle counter-app@0.1.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/mnt/d/project/excercises/node/react$9 verbose lifecycle counter-app@0.1.0~start: CWD: /mnt/d/project/excercises/node/react/counter-app
10 silly lifecycle counter-app@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle counter-app@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle counter-app@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: counter-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid counter-app@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /mnt/d/project/excercises/node/react/counter-app
16 verbose Linux 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft                                                                                                                          17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"                                                                                                    18 verbose node v8.10.0                                                                                                                                         19 verbose npm  v6.12.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error counter-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the counter-app@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

but if I simply use "npm start" it works perfectly, but I want to use port 80

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you already try to define the port when launching your server ?

`set PORT= 80 && node app.js`

You could also update your package.json to just use `npm run start`.
package.json:

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT= 80 && node app.js"
...
```

Comment: I did, bit it says I need administration privilege to use port below 1024

Comment: Okay then one simple solution would be to follow what's described in this answer, seems to be the most appropriate in your case : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23281401/5832851

Comment: thank you for your answer, the problem solved, I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/23281401/11561888 and it works

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for the wrong solution. It is a bad idea to run `npm start` with `sudo`.

Instead; you can **forward** port **80** to react's port **3000**

`sudo iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000`

https://coderwall.com/p/plejka/forward-port-80-to-port-3000

this is the simple way; but you can search for the `nginx` way if it is a production server

Good luck,

Comment: iptables is not supported in windows bash, but thank you for your answer, this might help other

Comment: @RamadhanFajarIhsan in windows; use `netsh` . For example, in Windows 10 `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 listenport=3000 connectaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=80`