# Load balancer not redirecting ports?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I have a node server running on an ec2 instance with AWS from port 3000 as the ec2-instance accessed through putty doesn't let me use port 80 which I assume is because it is already in use from something else. I've registered a domain and realise I need to include the port 3000 as part of the url, like `example.com:3000/`.

However I would like to not have the port number in the url.

I have tried using a load balancer and target group to route traffic from port 80 to 3000 however it doesnt seem to be working. It could be that I have not set up the load balancer and target group correctly. Can anyone tell me the way to set up a load balancer like this? Or another way to remove the port number?

I have set up the load balancer as follows:

- Load balancer has listener on port 80 which points to target group
- This target group is on port 80 with a target pointing to my ec2-instance at port 3000

[Load Balancer Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlNek.png)

[Target Group Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9cd1.png)

Comment: "It could be that I have not set up the load balancer and target group correctly. " - well, you have to provide **exact** details of your setup. How anyone should know what you setup incorrectly?

Comment: What does SSH have to with serving http traffic?

Comment: Have you check your app is up and running at your ec2 port 3000?

Comment: @webdev_jj yeh the domain works only if I put the :3000 at the end of the URL

Answer (score 0):

Set the target group to listen to port 3000, LB port 80 just means you receive only http. So you receive http on LB and the target group port is 3000.

Comment: still doesnt seem to be working

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of your LB and Target Group configuration? Make sure to hide all sensitive information.

Comment: Also please provide the message you get when you try to hit the page, is it connection refused or  timeout?

Comment: It says it refused to connect when going to the website with no port number specified

Comment: I have added images to question as links

Comment: Looks good? Make sure you are using http and not https when you try to hit in the browser.

Comment: Yeh I’m kinda lost on what to do now I’ll try some other ways to get around it

Comment: Can you enter the instance terminate your app that listens on port 3000 and run `python3 -m http.server 3000` this will start a simple http file server pointing on the directory where you run the command from. This way we can make sure it's not your applications problem. Also please post a screenshot of the message you get when hitting the browser along with the full url, ofc hide sensitive parts.

Comment: It does work with the :3000 on the end so I don’t think it’s a problem with the app

Comment: What does work with the :3000 mean?

Comment: Port 3000 like example.com:3000

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't able to use a load balancer to redirect traffic to port 80 to 3000 so if anyone still has advice it would still be appreciated.

If you simply want to not need the port number in the url, I was able to do it with the help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16573737/18175952) posted on another thread.

Cheers.